# Two company names joined with & - singular or plural

Tags: grammatical-number

AFMA & PFI invites you to attend the joint closing meeting... (or invite?)

Comment: Some companies use "&" instead of "and" in their names such as "Marks & Spencer", "Johnson & Johnson", etc. Their official registered names might be different, but that's not the issue. "AFMA and PFI jointly invite you..."

Answer (score 1):

It should be AFMA & PFI invite you (it is a plural subject).

However the source of the issue might be whether they are in fact two companies, in which case "&" is not correct usage (since it should only be used if it is one company made up of two names, as per the comment above - Marks & Spencer).